# Заполнить таблицу Tableview массивом случайных чисел

Tags: java, javafx

Имеется следующий код класса-контроллера

```
public class Controller {

int i=1;

@FXML
public Button btnOk = new Button();
@FXML
public Button btnClr = new Button();
@FXML
public TextField elemNumbers = new TextField();
@FXML
public TableView arrayTable = new TableView();

@FXML
public void okBtnAction() {
    String massGet = elemNumbers.getText();
    i = Integer.parseInt(massGet);
    ArrayList massive = new ArrayList();
    //Заполняем массив случайными числами
    for (int x = 0; x < i; x++) {
        massive.add(x, (int) (Math.random() * 100));
    }

    //Вставляем в таблицу необходимое количество столбцов
    for(int x = 0; x < i; x++) {
        arrayTable.getColumns().add(new TableColumn());

    }

}
```

---

Необходимо заполнить получившуюся таблицу значениями из этого массива(в одну строку), видимо, нужно добавить еще одну строку...

Comment: Как я понял, GUI базируется на fxml, а значит присваивать элементам интерфейса что-либо - нельзя. При формировании окна, фреймворк сам создаст и привет элементы интерфейса к их переменным. А теперь к теме вопроса: Вставка происходит единожды или может и несколько раз? Может всетаки другой элемент использовать а не таблицу?

Comment: "а значит присваивать элементам интерфейса что-либо - нельзя. " - Как это понимать? В задании сказано таблица...Значит надо использовать таблицу))@RiĥardBrugekĥaim

Comment: Вставка происходит несколько раз, пользователь вводить количество элементов массива, а программа заполняет его рандомно @RiĥardBrugekĥaim

Comment: 1) Я имею ввиду это: @FXML public Button btnOk = new Button();. Не нужно им объект присваивать, фреймворк сам это делает. Просто оставьте не объявленную переменную (2)Тоесть у вас все время увеличивается количество столбцов а не строк?Может всетаки ListView? Его можно настроить на горизонтальный список.

Comment: @RiĥardBrugekĥaim можно и так, но потом все равно с таблицами разбираться, а как это делать я не знаю....

Comment: То есть просто @FXML Button okbutton?

Comment: Да. Таблица удобна тем, что ее можно настроить так, чтобы заряжать в  нее объекты определенного класса в качестве строк. Вот тут пример http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/ru/part2/

Comment: @RiĥardBrugekĥaim да этот пример я видел. А как с listview разобраться, сможешь помочь?

Comment: Давай проще как ответ напишу.

Comment: Давай попробуем так.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для такой цели лучше подойдет ListView.

```
@FXML
ListView<Integer> list;

list.getItems().add(3);
```

Чтобы он отображался в строку, нужно задать параметр Orientation в HORIZONTAL.
Такой параметр есть в FXML (если вы пользуетесь конструктором)

Comment: Окей, спасибо, приду домой сделаю, если что спрошу ещё....)